# For Loop t.test, Comparing Means by Factor Class in R

Tags: r, for-loop, t-test

I want to loop a lot of one sided t.tests, comparing mean crop harvest value by pattern for a set of different crops.

My data is structured like this:

```
df <- data.frame("crop" = rep(c('Beans', 'Corn', 'Potatoes'), 10),
                 "value" = rnorm(n = 30),
                 "pattern" = rep(c("mono", "inter"), 15),
                 stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

I would like the output to provide results from a t.test, comparing mean harvest of each crop by pattern (i.e. compare harvest of mono-cropped potatoes to intercropped potatoes), where the alternative is greater value for the intercropped pattern.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using base R.

```
# Generate example data
df <- data.frame("crop" = rep(c('Beans', 'Corn', 'Potatoes'), 10),
                 "value" = rnorm(n = 30),
                 "pattern" = rep(c("inter", "mono"), 15),
                 stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

# Create a list which will hold the output of the test for each crop
  crops <- unique(df$crop)
  test_output <- vector('list', length = length(crops))
  names(test_output) <- crops

# For each crop, save the output of a one-sided t-test
  for (crop in crops) {
    # Filter the data to include only observations for the particular crop
    crop_data <- df[df$crop == crop,]
    # Save the results of a t-test with a one-sided alternative
    test_output[[crop]] <- t.test(formula = value ~ pattern,
                                  data = crop_data,
                                  alternative = 'greater')
  }
```

It's important to note that when calling `t-test` with the formula interface (e.g. `y ~ x`) and where your independent variable is a factor, then using the setting `alternative = 'greater'` will test whether the mean in the lower factor level (in the case of your data, `"inter"`) is greater than the mean in the higher factor level (here, that's `"mono"`).

Comment: Using `by` could eliminate `unique`, `vector`, `names`, `for`, and `[`  lines!

Comment: That's a great suggestion. I think it would be valuable to add that as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the elegant "tidyverse" approach, which makes use of the `tidy` function from `broom` which allows you to store the output of a t-test as a data frame.

Instead of a formal for loop, the `group_by` and `do` functions from the `dplyr` package are used to accomplish the same thing as a for loop.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

# Generate example data
  df <- data.frame("crop" = rep(c('Beans', 'Corn', 'Potatoes'), 10),
                   "value" = rnorm(n = 30),
                   "pattern" = rep(c("inter", "mono"), 15),
                   stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

# Group the data by crop, and run a t-test for each subset of data.
# Use the tidy function from the broom package
# to capture the t.test output as a data frame

  df %>% 
    group_by(crop) %>% 
    do(tidy(t.test(formula = value ~ pattern,
                   data = .,
                   alternative = 'greater')))
```

Comment: Yes! I was so close to this earlier. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Absolutely. Good luck solving your analysis problem!

Answer (score 0):

Consider `by`, object-oriented wrapper to `tapply` designed to subset a data frame by factor(s) and run operations on subsets:

```
t_test_list <- by(df, df$crop, function(sub) 
                   t.test(formula = value ~ pattern,
                          data = sub, alternative = 'greater')
                 )
```